# Prime Occurrence

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

Choose a digit(nonzero) at random. Choose another(0-9), and join the two together(the new digits go behind). Keep going until you end up with a prime number. What is the expected(average) number of digits that you have chosen?

Comment: Please give some context, including your own thoughts about the problem.  Is there any reason to believe the expected number of digits will be finite?

Comment: Do you need to choose another number if the first is prime?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437759/number-of-digits-until-a-prime-is-reached?rq=1)

Comment: There are infinite primes

Comment: No if the first is prime

Answer (score 1):

The prime counting function.

There are approximately $\frac {x}{\ln x}$ prime numbers less than $x.$

The number of 2 digit prime numbers is $\frac {100}{\ln 100} - \frac {10}{\ln 10}$

And the density of 2 digit prime numbers is about $\frac {\frac {100}{\ln 100} - \frac {10}{\ln 10}}{90} = \frac {4}{9\ln 10}$

The density of $n$ digit prime numbers $\rho_n \approx \frac {\frac {10}{n\ln 10} - \frac {1}{(n-1)\ln 10}}{9} \approx  \frac {1}{n\ln 10}$